# Given two column vectors $a$ and $b$, what is the determinant of $A$ if $A=Id-ab^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given two column vectors $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R^n$
, $n \ge 2$, form the $n×n$ matrix and  $I_n$ the identity matrix. Let be
$A = I_n-ab^T$. What is the determinant of $A$?

Comment: HINT: This is a rank 1 perturbation of $I_n$, so it only has one eigenvalue besides $1$. You can easily compute such an eigenvalue and then compute the determinant as the product of all eigenvalues.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By matrix determinant lemma, if $B$ is non-singular, $$\det(B+uv^T)=(1+v^TB^{-1}u)\det(B).$$

Hence, $$\det(I-ab^T)=1-b^Ta.$$